# Removing an entire key from a JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This may be a case of my lack of terminology, however if someone could enlighten me on this I'd appreciate it:

I have a routine which returns a JSON array, works perfectly however I then wish to do some calculations based on what's passed.

I've therefore copied the array into a temporary object (called tmp), and I then wish to remove certain 'keys' (?) from this object that aren't necessary.

For example, my 'tmp' object starts out as having:

fldCat2, fldCat3 and many more.

What I don't need is anything related to 'fldCat3', so I wish to remove that entire key from the object.

To test this I've done the following:

```
        console.log(tmp);

        delete tmp.fldCat3;
        delete tmp['fldCat3'];

        var prop = "fldCat3";
        delete tmp[prop];

        console.log(tmp);
```

Yet not one of those delete methods deletes 'fldCat3' from the tmp object.

Is there something pretty damn obvious I'm missing?

*edit*

have attached a screenshot of the object from within Firebug (values removed)

[image: FireBug output]

Comment: You probably haven't supplied enough of your code, because the snippet you've posted has no problem with deleting the `fldCat3` key from the `tmp` object.

Comment: Both delete tmp.fldCat3 & delete tmp['fldCat3'] should work just fine. Can you paste an entire chunk of code that is not working as expected, including creation of the object?

Comment: Amended question with screenshot.

Comment: The object of the screenshot is not an object with those properties. Instead this an array of multiple objects containing these properties. Is this not correct?

Comment: @JacobT.Nielsen - that's just helped me immensely, thank you, you are right, the Object is containing a further array of multiple Objects which simply isn't correct at all (or rather a very silly way of doing things!)  Thank you again, will change accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your screenshot I am assuming that your problem is that you are trying to remove properties from what is actually an array of objects with these properties.

You will have to do something like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++)
    delete tmp[i].fldCat3;
```

Here you loop through all the elements of said array removing fldCat3 from each of these.

Comment: Perfect!!!! And as per your help earlier, will change accordingly, thanks Jacob, much appreciated.

Comment: @JasonMHirst Good to hear. I am glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced that problem too. What I have done is using [UnderscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org/#compact)'s `_.compact(myObject)` after deleting the key from the object.

Comment: Fantastic library, thanks for showing me this, will help with other things like grouping!